# going to full screen messes up ggplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is either a bug in ggplot or a bug in my brain.

The double green bar at height 27 should be a single line.  It is defined by two x values and a single y value twice:

[image]

Even worse, if I expand the image to full screen more of these fly apart

[image]

Does anyone have any insight into this? Thanks.

```
ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=plotData,
              aes(x=x,y=y,group=interaction(y,type),color=color,
                  size=lineSize,linetype=lineType)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=group.colors) +
    ggtitle('EScells') +
    xlab('chr2') +
    ylab('')
```

Comment: For future reference, if you want to include data in a reproducible format, the best way to do this is use `dput(plotData)`. Copy and paste the output into the question

Answer (score 2):

Not surprisingly, the bug was in my brain.  ggplot was treating the lines in question as dashed lines.  Some of these dashed lines only became visible as dashes in the larger sized image.